# Noindex Session ID pages with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string, noindex, mod-headers

I have many pages with the parameter `SID=` indexed in Google which I would like to `noindex`, eg `https://www.example.com.au/checkout/cart/?SID=c79e6055436bf371a02f4d2601cecd03`

I have used the following code in htaccess but it doesn't seem to match?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^SID=$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=NOINDEXFOLLOW:true]
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `RewriteCond` directive, you are trying to match against:

```
^SID=$
```

which means, that the `%{QUERY_STRING}` will start with `SID=` and has nothing else after that. This is not the case here. Update the code to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^SID=
RewriteRule ^ - [env=NOINDEXFOLLOW:true]

Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=NOINDEXFOLLOW
```